# Initial SessionFactory creation failed.java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/mortbay/log/Log

Tags: java, hibernate

I created a web project in Eclipse and executed it succesfuly (used hibernate), I want to develop a java-application continue using this hibernate with the project and tried to execute it, but it throws the following error:

> Initial SessionFactory creation failed.java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/mortbay/log/Log

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you please post the configuration of your session factory?

Answer (score 0):

The error is string forward.. U might have not included the classfile/library on the class path.. this exception will be thrown when JVM was not able to find the class file..

Cheers!